# grub-emu is displaying garbage text

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a remote server running Ubuntu 18.04. When I ran apt upgrade today, I got an error message from grub that original boot device is not found, asking me to select the disk for installing boot loader. As per the suggestion on the prompt, I selected all listed devices. But I still got some error messages when installing the boot loader.

I tried to run `grub-emu` to verify that the bootloader is installed correctly. I am getting the following screen, with lots of garbage text. What is wrong?

[image]

I am connected to the remote server via SSH, from a Mac OSX terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this as well. I discovered that `grub-emu` actually tries to open a separate window to display the emulated menu and fails in the manner you described if X forwarding is not enabled.

To ssh with X-forwarding enabled, add the `-Y` option to `ssh`.

Comment: I have migrated to a new server, so I cannot verify your solution. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had never heard of grub-emu before.
I installed it on my test server and got the same as you from both remote via ssh and local at the terminal.
I installed it on a test Ubuntu 18.04 desktop and it worked fine (albeit annoying to use), opening an independent window when launched.

Conclusion: It isn't for servers, only desktops with fancy GUI stuff.

Comment: That is not correct. I had tested it on a different server running Ubuntu Server 18.04 and it was working correctly.

Comment: Interesting. I do not know how it can work on a server, with no GUI. It uses two windows, typing goes in the original windows and the second windows displays the grub menu. I have searched and searched, but haven't gained further insight.